# parse nested javascript array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this array

```
  air_content: '',
  compaction_method: 1,
  concrete_cylinders: [
    {
      id: '',
      specimen_name: 'A',
      mould_number: '',
      curing: 1,
      age: 7
    },
    {
      id: '',
      specimen_name: 'A',
      mould_number: '',
      curing: 1,
      age: 7
    },
    {
      id: '',
      specimen_name: 'A',
      mould_number: '',
      curing: 1,
      age: 7
    }
  ]
```

I'm trying to parse them when i post the data ( formik modifies them back to text so i am required to parse them as int for my backend )

My post looks like this ( this works except for the nested objects i want them parsed as integer also )

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8123/samples/concrete', {
  air_content: parseFloat(air_content),
  compaction_method: parseInt(compaction_method),
  concrete_cylinders
});
```

the psuedo/My best try of the code of what I'm trying to do is the below

```
   axios.post('http://localhost:8123/samples/concrete', {
      air_content: parseFloat(air_content),
      compaction_method: parseInt(compaction_method),
      concrete_cylinders: {
        [concrete_cylinders.id]: parseInt(concrete_cylinders.id),
        [concrete_cylinders.curing]: parseInt(concrete_cylinders.curing)
      }
    });
```

Thankyou for assistance

Comment: there is no nested array in the question ...

Comment: the nested object sorry the concrete_cylinders

Comment: All good, I kinda figured that is what you wanted to deal with - see answer

Comment: If they are numeric in object as shown then they should stay numeric when parsed to json

Comment: @charlietfl There is something weird with formik when tho i have them set to number convert back to string somehow.. i've searched alot on google and cannot find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before calling axios.post you'll need to

```
concrete_cylinders.forEach(x => {
    x.id = parseInt(x.id);
    x.curing = parseInt(c.curing);
});
```

or, if you really want, you can do it like

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8123/samples/concrete', {
  air_content: parseFloat(air_content),
  compaction_method: parseInt(compaction_method),
  concrete_cylinders: concrete_cylinders.map(x => {
    x.id = parseInt(x.id);
    x.curing = parseInt(c.curing);
    return x;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using the newer [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```js
const concrete_cylinders = [
  {
    id: '',
    specimen_name: 'A',
    mould_number: '',
    curing: '1',
    age: '7'
  },
  {
    id: '',
    specimen_name: 'A',
    mould_number: '',
    curing: '1',
    age: '7'
  },
  {
    id: '',
    specimen_name: 'A',
    mould_number: '',
    curing: '1',
    age: '7'
  }
]

const result = concrete_cylinders.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  ...{
    curing: parseInt(o.curing),
    age: parseInt(o.age)
  }
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try using `forEach` on the array before posting. So for example...

```js
pojo = {
  air_content: '',
  compaction_method: 1,
  concrete_cylinders: [
    {
      id: '3',
      specimen_name: 'A',
      mould_number: '',
      curing: '1',
      age: 7
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      specimen_name: 'A',
      mould_number: '',
      curing: '1',
      age: 7
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      specimen_name: 'A',
      mould_number: '',
      curing: '1',
      age: 7
    }
  ]
}

pojo.concrete_cylinders.forEach(e => {
  e.id = parseFloat(e.id)
  e.curing = parseInt(e.curing)
//...anything else you want to change before posting
})
```

Then pass the object to your `axios.post`

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8123/samples/concrete', pojo);
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this in less lines, but this should solve your problem.